# Count messages from a Discord server - Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, count, bots, discord.js

Good afternoon,

I want to create a Discord Bot who can collect and count messages from a Guild for a specific mentioned user and to be possible to fetch the messages from a certain time to a certain time.

My command I want to look like this

```
*messages @user [date | periodOfTime]
```

I tried doing the part of when @user is mentioned to show its messages from that specific guild.

```
        db.add(`globalMessages_${message.author.id}`, 1);
        db.add(`guildMessages_${message.guild.id}_${message.author.id}`, 1);

        // Programing command

        async function messageCount() {
            let member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.member;

            let guild = await db.fetch(`guildMessages_${member.guild.id}_${member.id}`);

            message.channel.send(`**Guild Messages: \`${guild}\`**`);

        }    

        messageCount();
```

I run this code but it's not tracking as it should. It's just incremeting the command `*messages` ...

How can I make this command work as I wish?

Thank you for any kind of help.

Comment: if you don’t mind me asking, what database are you using? sql? oh and what do you mean by it’s not tracking?

Answer (score 1):

Try Doing What I did below in the second/first line.

```
db.add(`globalmessages_${message.author.id}`, +=1)
```